# is quartz.net meant to support triggers of less than 1 second in duration?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

Is quartz.net meant to support triggers of less than 1 second in duration?

I'm assuming no, as I don't see any method like TriggerUtils.MakeMilliSecondlyTrigger for example.  I'm assuming therefore you would for such short durations be better looking at creating a thread and just using Thread.Sleep perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quartz.NET supports less than 1 second intervals with SimpleTrigger. They usually just are a bit quite uncommon use case and the infrastructure might become bottleneck when you reach < 100ms intervals  creating jobs, handling misfires etc, all depends on your CPU basically).

TriggerUtils doesn't give your shorthands for this as it's not the common case. RAMJobStore would be the right choice here as it performs drastically better for these kind of scheduling needs.

Answer (score 2):

The Trigger Class does have a [HasMillisecondsPrecision Property](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/topic682.html)

That I believe is what you're looking for. Where the documentation says:

> Tells whether this Trigger instance
>   can handle events in millisecond
>   precision.

Comment: oh, so I would have to use another technique to create the trigger as opposed to my current "TriggerUtils.MakeSecondlyTrigger(_intervalInSeconds)" then I guess?